# Set focus on a modeless dialogs hosted in an MFC view

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

I have an MFC view, and I have another project which implements and MFC dialog.
I want to host the dialog in my view.
My view is of class CFormView.

I did it that way in my view code:

`m_myDialog->Create(myDialog::IDD, this);`

Now, I see my dialog, but I can't set focus on it and can't use it.

What do I have to change in order to host my dialog in my view, and be able to use it and set focus to it, just as part of the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a few weeks old, but you need to provide more code or a better context of what is taking place.

I had a similar problem to yourself & found this hard to find info on when I first tried this. Following is an abstract of something I've used. I'm sure there's probably a better way to do this, but I find it works the way I want;

```
        //MyApp.h

        class MyDialogClass;

        class MyApp : public CWinAppEx
        {
        public:
            MyApp();
            virtual BOOL InitInstance();
            //code etc
            MyDialogClass *p_myDlg;
        };


        //MyApp.cpp
        #include "MyApp.h"
        #include "CMyView.h"
        #include "mydialogclass.h"


        BOOL MyApp::InitInstance()
        {
        //code etc

            p_myDlg = CMyView::GetView()->p_myDlg;  

        //can be used here or elsewhere. I have mine linked with a button
            p_myDlg->ShowWindow(true);

        };


        //CMyView.h

        class MyDialogClass;

        class CMyView : public CFormView
        {
         protected: // create from serialization only
            CMyView();
            DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyView)

         public:
            enum{ IDD = IDD_CMyView_VIEW };

                static CMyView* GetView();
                MyDialogClass *p_myDlg;
            afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
        };


        //CMyView.cpp
        #include "MyApp.h"
        #include "CMyView.h"
        #include "mydialogclass.h"

        int CMyView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
        {
            if (CFormView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
                return -1;

            p_myDlg = new MyDialogClass(this);

            return 0;
        }

        void CMyView::DisplayDialogFoo()
        {

           //can be used here or elsewhere. I have mine linked with a button
           p_myDlg->ShowWindow(true);

        }

        //mydialogclass.h
        class MyDialogClass : public CDialog
        {
            DECLARE_DYNAMIC(MyDialogClass)
         public:
            MyDialogClass(CWnd* pParent /*= NULL*/);
            enum { IDD = IDD_MyDialog_DLG };
        };

        //mydialogclass.cpp
        #include "mydialogclass.h"

        MyDialogClass::MyDialogClass(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
            : CDialog(MyDialogClass::IDD, pParent)
        {
            Create(IDD, pParent);
        }
```

There's also an article here I just found:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1651/Tutorial-Modeless-Dialogs-with-MFC